# Portrait and Landscape view capability to my Iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have made a iphone app which working fine in portrait mode.now how i can made it for landscape mode that it will work fine on changing of orientation.should I use frame for every component or use another view for landscape mode...?please some body help me to way out from this problem

Answer (score 0):

Alok,

This actually has to be done according to your requirements as you might need the same in Landscape Mode. So there will be a need to check each n every screen. Simple start with setAutoresize to yes, likewise you need to resize/adjust frames.

Comment: thanks Tarun but can you please tell me how and where i use set autoresizing or frame

Comment: PLEASE HELP! I've spent five days now trying to figure this out, and I'm sure it's something very simple that I'm doing wrong, but I'll be hanged if I know what it is...

Comment: hi Tarun i have got a way to change the component position through frame.it works fine but bit lenthy